One window not remember its position on external monitor
I've just reinstalled my Mac version MacOS 14.6 Sonoma. This is a Macbook Air M2 with a UWQHD external monitor, via USB-C.
When I unplug/plug my external monitor or just wake up my Mac, all windows that were previously in the external monitor are automatically moved to it, in the previous position. Except one that doesn't move. It is Arc Browser if it could make a difference, but I didn't have this problem before with my old Mac M1.
I don't want to use any 3rd app before it seems that it should work without. I've checked old questions but they are really old. I tried Mission Control settings, all other applications are set to "None", I've tried to set Arc Browser to "Display 1" (and None) or "Display 2" but nothing works.
